# Why do stable enols give positive ferric chloride test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

It is known that phenol and all its derivatives give violet colour with neutral alkaline ferric chloride solution. However I also found out that stable enols, like 2,4 di-oxo pentane, also give this test. The reason eludes me.

Comment: The reason has to do with the complex formed. Not only phenols, but stable enols also form colored complexes with ferric chloride.

Comment: Can you be specific. Like what complex?

Comment: Ferric chloride forms an octahedral complex. For example, the phenol complex would be $\ce{[Fe(OPh)6]^{3-}}$

Comment: I tried looking for a possible complex but came up with nothing. If you could state the complex formed with enols, it would be appreciated.